# How can we check our mail service and how to stop outgoing emails from linux Server

Tags: linux, system-administration

How can we check that what Mail service are we using in Linux. How to stop outgoing emails from mail server.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use command   telnet your.server.name 25